# Semi-open triangles topology is not a product topology

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

In order to give an example of a topology of $\Bbb{R}^2$ which is not the product of a topology of $\Bbb{R}$, I have seen on a book the topology $\mathcal{T}$ of semi-open triangles induced by the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{ V(p,\varepsilon) : p \in \Bbb{R}^2, \varepsilon > 0 \}$ where given $p=(a,b)$ and $\varepsilon > 0 $ we denote $$V(p,\varepsilon) := \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : a \leq x < a + \varepsilon \, ; \, b - (x - a) \leq y \leq b + x - a \}$$

The book affirms that this topology can not be described as a product topology but it does not show it, so if anyone knows a proof or another source to consult, I would appreciate it so much.

Comment: Can you solve this problem for the topology on $\mathbb R$ given by half-open intervals (the lower or the upper limit topology)?

Comment: @MoisheKohan No, I do not know how to do it, it seems difficult to me

Comment: Then you should start by thinking about the lower limit topology. Did you already learn about connectedness?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, I know the concept and its propperties. What relation has with this? I first thought about it and other concepts that remains on the product like compactness, path connectedness, countable axioms and separation but I did not have ideas to apply it since there are topologies many topologies on $\Bbb{R}$ .

Comment: Hmm, I guess I was not clear enough: 1. You are not ready for the problems about topologies on $\mathbb R^2$. 2. Work on solving the problem about the lower limit topology on $\mathbb R$ using the concept of connectedness.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Do you mean to prove that the Lower limit topology is not a product topology? I do not understand it, this topology is of $\Bbb{R}$ not of $\Bbb{R}^2$

Comment: No, that the lower limit topology is not the standard one.

Comment: What do you mean by standard?

Comment: The order topology (with the basis consisting of intervals $(a,b)$, $a<b$).

Comment: I do not understand, what does it have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove that the subspace topology on every vertical line is discrete and the subspace topology on every horizontal line is the lower limit topology (LLT). Also prove that your topology is not the product of discrete topology and the LTT. Then finish the proof that this topology is not a product topology.

Comment: Of course, another downvote of a correct answer...